# Taking a list of 2-d arrays and getting the non-zero values as ones in a single array with Numpy

Tags: numpy

I have a list of 2-d numpy arrays, and I wish to create one array consisting of the non-zero values (or-wise) of each array set to 1. For example

```
arr1 = np.array([[1,0],[0,0]])
arr2 = np.array([[0,10],[0,0]])
arr3 = np.array([[0,0],[0,8]])
arrs = [arr1, arr2, arr3]
```

And so my op would yield

```
op(arrs) = [[1, 1], [0, 1]]]
```

What is an efficient way to do this in numpy (for about 8 image arrays of 600 by 600)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a while to understand. Try just summing all the arrays keeping their dimensions and then replace non-zero values with `1` as follows-

```py
def op(arrs):
    return np.where(np.add.reduce(arrs) != 0, 1, 0)
```